# Rmarkdown - Duplicated TOC (Table of content)

Tags: r, r-markdown

Hello StackOverflow community,

- When creating an Rmarkdown document all goes fine and table of content appears as intended.

*TOC Correct:*

[image]

---

- When I open the HTML in my browser from Rstudio to my browser it does as well appear correctly.

  The issue happens when I save that HTML and open it later on or send it to somebody, the TOC would then appear duplicated.

*TOC with duplicated items:*

[image]

Below is the code used regarding the toc in my .rmd file.

```
  output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float : true
```

Would you know what I am doing wrong or might be missing. Thanks in advance for any feedback!

Comment: As additional comment- when taking out the toc_float statement it does not duplicate even when saving the file - and re-opening it later. Hope it might help.

Comment: Difficult to say without more code, but worth a shot -- make sure `html_document` is indented as seen in `section 3.1.1` on [this guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html).

Comment: I can reproduce this. When saving the HTML n Firefox, the TOC gets duplicated and the elements have duplicate IDs. This seems to be a bug. Why do you save the HTML anyways? It has already been created by knitr?

Comment: Hello Jason, Martin - thanks for taking the time. Martin, I save the HTML to be able to share it afterward - is there a better approach? Jason - I used that guide to produce the TOC originally. Thanks though!

Comment: When you knit a .Rmd, usually it knits and then generates a HTML document. When you say "save that HTML", do you mean that you open that HTML document and then do "Save As" from the browser? In which case, why not just share the HTML document generated by knitting the .Rmd? Or are we misunderstanding you?

Comment: Hello @divibisan - I was not aware that actually a copy of the HTML was saved/generated within the folder where the .rmd file sits. Hence was trying to open the Rstudio output in the browser (via the "open in browser" button) and then saving that output. 
Then in that second HTML that I saved there was duplication of the "TOC" (as well as breaking the link) and had as well impacts on the "Tabs" function.