# TOC problem when knitting Rmarkdown document with images

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, tableofcontents

Finished and published on github my first website using Distill package in RStudio:
https://crlnp.github.io/3-objets.html

On this particular page I include several images in my rmarkdown document and it causes problems with the table of contents: the headings are duplicated and don't follow the headings adequatly. I have tried every toc_float: option available and it does not solve the problem. Aldo tried changing the heading levels (all #, ...). The problem appears wether the image is inserted traditionally or in a code bloc. If I take out the images in my file, the TOC works perfectly. I have not been able to find any information on this issue. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I _can_ reproduce this same duplication on my own machine. Unfortunately I cannot see anything which you are doing wrong! I believe this is a bug

Comment: Here's a link to a similar (also unresolved) question from last year https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653271/rmarkdown-duplicated-toc-table-of-content

Comment: Oh well... Many thanks for checking this out!

Answer (score 0):

Your `.Rmd` [file](https://github.com/CRLNP/CRLNP.github.io/blob/master/3-objets.Rmd) on the website (GitHub) repo.
If you include JS file (optional) and move wrapping div container, from current position to above your first header, TOC behaviour will change:

```
<script src="hideOutput.js"></script>
<div class="fold o">
## 1. Les objets
.
.
.
</div>
```

Is this helpful in any way?

Output:
[image]

Comment: Hello Radovan, Wow it worked! Just by putting the <div> up top. Many thanks for taking the time... Cheers!

Comment: Glad I could help. Keep developing such a notable resource!