# How to fix duplicated TOC in RMD file while using toc_float and columns

Tags: html, web, r-markdown, multiple-columns, tableofcontents

I made an Rmd website through github. For one html page, I have an rknit setup with a floating TOC (table of contents), and each content scrolls to lower part of page with content details. The details are a written description plus an image. However, ever since I added the following to make div columns and put images to the right or left of the text, the TOC gets repeated:

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 30px;">
<div class="col-sm-6">
```

see the TOC at the webpage: https://cymfroehlich.github.io/projects.html

Here is the full code:

````
    ---
title: "RESEARCH PROJECTS"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    collapsed: false
    number_sections: false
    toc_depth: 1
    #code_folding: hide
---

![](images/slide3s.png)

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message=FALSE,warning=FALSE, cache=TRUE)
```

# Linking Animal Behaviour, Mutualisms and Environmental Change

<div class="row" style="padding-top: 30px;">
<div class="col-sm-6">

As environmental disturbances become more intense and frequent, there are many changes that have been documented at population levels and ecosystem levels. We have yet to uncover how such disturbances affect the behaviour of animals, which is critical for the maintenance of many populations and could prove detrimental to particular species or even groups of species. Importantly, many animal relationships exist among different organisms, and mutualistic relationships are key for the maintenance of several ecosystems. Accordingly, changes to animal behaviours and ecological relationships may have flow-on effects on ecosystems. For my research, I aim to delve deeper into the potential environmental consequences on animal behaviour for mutualistic organisms. I use a combination of observational, manipulative, and phylogenetic approaches to link animal behaviour and environmental change for coral-dwelling gobies, which live exclusively in some of the corals most susceptible to coral damage and death from cyclones and bleaching-induced heatwaves.

Collaborators: Marian Y.L. Wong, O. Selma Klanten, Siobhan J. Heatwole, Martin L. Hing, Mark Dowton


</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">

<a href = "https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2021.01.13.426488v1">
![](images/DNAExtract_TaggedGoby.jpg)

![](images/slide1s.png)
</a>
</div>

# Social Behaviour of Coral Reef Fishes

<div class="row" style="padding-top: 30px;">
<div class="col-sm-6">

<a href = "https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fmars.2021.665780/full"> ![](images/GobyAnemonefishMutualismSociality.jpg)
</a>


</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">

Animals often live in groups temporarily or permanently for a variety of ecological, social, and life history reasons. For several marine fishes, size hierarchies are established to maintain the peace in which the two biggest individuals breed and the rest control their growth and forgo reproduction to maintain group membership. I aim to uncover key evolutionary mechanisms for the maintenance of group membership and size hierarchies in such animals. Two fish groups that are of particular focus for my research are coral-dwelling gobies and anemonefishes.

Collaborators: Marian Y.L. Wong, O. Selma Klanten, Siobhan J. Heatwole, Martin L. Hing, Theresa Rueger, Peter M. Buston, Rebecca Branconi

</div>

# Fisheries Management and Animal Behaviour

<div class="row" style="padding-top: 30px;">
<div class="col-sm-6">

Over decades and centuries, fisheries have changed fish populations and we are only beginning to understand the degree of these impacts. Management agencies have used available monitoring data to attempt to remove overfishing stress for many taxa, yet many species are continuing to experience excessive fishing pressure. Many fish are exhibiting behavioural changes, size truncations and lower reproductive capacity from fishing pressure, which have detrimental consequences on population maintenance and conservation. Accordingly, my research aims to understand how fish movement, size and growth, and reproduction are affected by fisheries, and to provide suggestions to improve management of these fisheries. I have particular experience with red snapper, <i>Lutjanus campechanus</i>.

Collaborators: Richard J. Kline, Andres Garcia, Carlos E. Cintra-Buenrostro, Adam M. Lee, Ramiro Oquita, David W. Hicks, J. Dale Shively, J. Brooke Shipley

</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">

 ![](images/10014876_10152148903631794_1171996106372918196_o.jpg)
[Image by Seth Patterson](https://www.flickr.com/photos/spatterd/)

</div>

# Artificial Reef Research

<div class="row" style="padding-top: 30px;">
<div class="col-sm-6">

![](images/slide2s.png)
 ![](images/Culverts. picture taken by seth patterson.jpg)
[Image by Seth Patterson](https://www.flickr.com/photos/spatterd/)

</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">

Artificial reefs (i.e., man-made reefs) are critical habitat for many marine taxa that live in environments with limited natural habitat and/or degraded habitat. Although artificial reefs have been deployed or accidentally created (e.g. through shipwrecks) for decades and centuries, we have yet to understand the optimal arrangements and structural characteristics necessary for artificial reefs to mimic natural habitat. Accordingly, my research aims to identify optimal habitat characteristics and formations for the deployment of artificial reef habitat that effectively mimics natural habitat.

Collaborators: Richard J. Kline, Andres Garcia, Carlos E. Cintra-Buenrostro, Adam M. Lee, Rachel N. Arney, Ramiro Oquita, David W. Hicks


</div>


# Teamwork makes the dream work

None of this could be done without the helpful team of collaborators, colleagues, field assistants, boat captains, volunteers, reef station managers, local help, and our support system. Thank you everyone!

![](images/slide4s.png)
````

Interestingly, this issue doesn't happen if I remove toc_float: true, because then it lists each project with link up top for a TOC, but does not duplicated the TOC.

Can you please help me figure out what went wrong once I added div columns?

Note: I have the repeated TOC issue within Rstudio when I build the website and view it, as well as the HTML file itself, and on the website. This is slightly different to the follow question (most similar issue) that was asked but not solved in which the replicated TOC was only seen in some steps: [Rmarkdown - Duplicated TOC (Table of content)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653271/rmarkdown-duplicated-toc-table-of-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix. You just need to close all `<div class="row">` elements:

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 30px;">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
  Content...
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
  Content...
  </div>
</div>    <--- missing closing </div> tag
```

````
---
title: "RESEARCH PROJECTS"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    collapsed: false
    number_sections: false
    toc_depth: 1
    #code_folding: hide
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message=FALSE,warning=FALSE, cache=TRUE)
```

![](images/slide3s.png)

# Linking Animal Behaviour, Mutualisms and Environmental Change

<div class="row" style="padding-top: 30px;">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
As environmental disturbances become more intense and frequent, there are many changes that have been documented at population levels and ecosystem levels. We have yet to uncover how such disturbances affect the behaviour of animals, which is critical for the maintenance of many populations and could prove detrimental to particular species or even groups of species. Importantly, many animal relationships exist among different organisms, and mutualistic relationships are key for the maintenance of several ecosystems. Accordingly, changes to animal behaviours and ecological relationships may have flow-on effects on ecosystems. For my research, I aim to delve deeper into the potential environmental consequences on animal behaviour for mutualistic organisms. I use a combination of observational, manipulative, and phylogenetic approaches to link animal behaviour and environmental change for coral-dwelling gobies, which live exclusively in some of the corals most susceptible to coral damage and death from cyclones and bleaching-induced heatwaves.

Collaborators: Marian Y.L. Wong, O. Selma Klanten, Siobhan J. Heatwole, Martin L. Hing, Mark Dowton
  </div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
<a href = "https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2021.01.13.426488v1">
![](images/DNAExtract_TaggedGoby.jpg)
![](images/slide1s.png)
</a>
  </div>
</div>

# Social Behaviour of Coral Reef Fishes

<div class="row" style="padding-top: 30px;">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
<a href = "https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fmars.2021.665780/full"> 
![](images/GobyAnemonefishMutualismSociality.jpg)
</a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
Animals often live in groups temporarily or permanently for a variety of ecological, social, and life history reasons. For several marine fishes, size hierarchies are established to maintain the peace in which the two biggest individuals breed and the rest control their growth and forgo reproduction to maintain group membership. I aim to uncover key evolutionary mechanisms for the maintenance of group membership and size hierarchies in such animals. Two fish groups that are of particular focus for my research are coral-dwelling gobies and anemonefishes.

Collaborators: Marian Y.L. Wong, O. Selma Klanten, Siobhan J. Heatwole, Martin L. Hing, Theresa Rueger, Peter M. Buston, Rebecca Branconi
  </div>
</div>

# Fisheries Management and Animal Behaviour

<div class="row" style="padding-top: 30px;">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
Over decades and centuries, fisheries have changed fish populations and we are only beginning to understand the degree of these impacts. Management agencies have used available monitoring data to attempt to remove overfishing stress for many taxa, yet many species are continuing to experience excessive fishing pressure. Many fish are exhibiting behavioural changes, size truncations and lower reproductive capacity from fishing pressure, which have detrimental consequences on population maintenance and conservation. Accordingly, my research aims to understand how fish movement, size and growth, and reproduction are affected by fisheries, and to provide suggestions to improve management of these fisheries. I have particular experience with red snapper, <i>Lutjanus campechanus</i>.

Collaborators: Richard J. Kline, Andres Garcia, Carlos E. Cintra-Buenrostro, Adam M. Lee, Ramiro Oquita, David W. Hicks, J. Dale Shively, J. Brooke Shipley
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
![](images/10014876_10152148903631794_1171996106372918196_o.jpg)
[Image by Seth Patterson](https://www.flickr.com/photos/spatterd/)
  </div>
</div>

# Artificial Reef Research

<div class="row" style="padding-top: 30px;">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
![](images/slide2s.png)
![](images/Culverts. picture taken by seth patterson.jpg)
[Image by Seth Patterson](https://www.flickr.com/photos/spatterd/)
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
Artificial reefs (i.e., man-made reefs) are critical habitat for many marine taxa that live in environments with limited natural habitat and/or degraded habitat. Although artificial reefs have been deployed or accidentally created (e.g. through shipwrecks) for decades and centuries, we have yet to understand the optimal arrangements and structural characteristics necessary for artificial reefs to mimic natural habitat. Accordingly, my research aims to identify optimal habitat characteristics and formations for the deployment of artificial reef habitat that effectively mimics natural habitat.

Collaborators: Richard J. Kline, Andres Garcia, Carlos E. Cintra-Buenrostro, Adam M. Lee, Rachel N. Arney, Ramiro Oquita, David W. Hicks
  </div>
</div>


# Teamwork makes the dream work

None of this could be done without the helpful team of collaborators, colleagues, field assistants, boat captains, volunteers, reef station managers, local help, and our support system. Thank you everyone!

![](images/slide4s.png)
````

Output:
[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for pointing that out. Makes complete sense. Fixed now.